# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Getting this error on issue "mysql" command on Ubuntu machine:

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)

The service is not starting with following error:

```
root@bettorssidekick:/# service mysql start

start: Job failed to start

root@bettorssidekick:/#
```

Restarted the service and it wont run again. Here is the final log entries from mysql log:

```
110824 12:03:36 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.

110824 12:03:36  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M

110824 12:03:36  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

110824 12:03:36  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233

110824 12:03:36 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events

110824 12:03:36 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.

Version: '5.1.54-1ubuntu4'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)

110902  5:34:04 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Disk is full writing './bettorssidekick/schedules.MYD' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to free space... (Expect up to 60 secs delay for server to contin$

110902  5:34:04 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs

110902  5:36:02 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Disk is full writing './bettorssidekick/cronejob.MYD' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to free space... (Expect up to 60 secs delay for server to continu$

110902  5:36:02 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs

110902  5:44:04 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
```

Comment: The error already tell you what is the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
110902  5:34:04 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Disk is full writing ...
```

Problem: Your Hard disk is full

Solution: **Delete some files**

Answer (score 0):

I tried with different ways that I got instructions from different sources. However, I just changed the traffic rules and then its working for me. Make sure what are rules you are specific supposedly, ssh, http, custom tcp rule, RDB like that. If you are sure then fix the rules otherwise open for all traffic.

Answer (score -2):

Please check below URL that will Help you to resolve your problem.

[MySQL ERROR 2002 (HY000)](http://technologiessolution.blogspot.in/2013/12/mysql-error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to.html)

This Link will show you details Why  this error will generated and how to resolve this issue.