# 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111 "Connection refused")'

Tags: mariadb, galera, mariasql

I am trying to setup mariadb galera cluster on Debian Wheezy 7.5. I have found many different instructions, all a bit different, but none have worked thus far.

I am trying to setup a two node cluster.

On the primary node, I am using the default my.cnf, with these additional settings in conf.d/cluster.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
#mysql settings
bind-address=10.1.1.139
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
binlog_format=ROW
default_storage_engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_doublewrite=1

#galery settings
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://10.1.1.139,10.1.1.140"
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_cluster_name="sql_cluster"
wsrep_node_incoming_address=10.1.1.139
wsrep_sst_receive_address=10.1.1.139
wsrep_sst_auth=cluster:password
wsrep_node_address='10.1.1.139'
wsrep_node_name='sql1'
wsrep_on=ON
```

Created the cluster user, gave that user all the required permissions, started the server successfully with

```
service mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster
```

The cluster starts up, I can see `cluster_size=1`;

On the second node, I am using the default my.cnf, with these additional settings in conf.d/cluster.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
#mysql settings
bind-address=10.1.1.140
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
binlog_format=ROW
default_storage_engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_doublewrite=1

#galery settings
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://10.1.1.139,10.1.1.140"
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_cluster_name="sql_cluster"
wsrep_node_incoming_address=10.1.1.140
wsrep_sst_receive_address=10.1.1.140
wsrep_sst_auth=cluster:password
wsrep_node_address='10.1.1.140'
wsrep_node_name='sql1'
wsrep_on=ON
```

I also replaced debian.cnf on the secondary node with the one from the primary node as per this suggestion:

http://docs.openstack.org/high-availability-guide/content/ha-aa-db-mysql-galera.html and granted the appropriate permissions (this was also suggested in other places, don't have the links right now).

Contents of debian.cnf on both nodes:

```
[client]
host = localhost
user = debian-sys-maint
password = <password>
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
host = localhost
user = debian-sys-maint
password = <password>
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir = /usr
```

When I try to start the second node with:

`service mysql start`

It fails, and I get this in /var/log/syslog:

```
May  7 19:45:30 ns514282 mysqld_safe: Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
May  7 19:45:30 ns514282 mysqld_safe: WSREP: Running position recovery with --log_error='/var/lib/mysql/wsrep_recovery.s6Uwyc' --pid-file='/var/lib/mysql/ns514282.ip-167-114-159.net-recover.pid'
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld_safe: WSREP: Recovered position 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_start_position var submitted: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1'
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, skipping position init
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library '/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so'
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): Galera 3.9(rXXXX) by Codership Oy <info@codership.com> loaded successfully.
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: CRC-32C: using hardware acceleration.
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: Found saved state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: Passing config to GCS: base_host = 10.1.1.142; base_port = 4567; cert.log_conflicts = no; debug = no; evs.auto_evict = 0; evs.delay_margin = PT1S; evs.delayed_keep_period = PT30S; evs.inactive_check_period = PT0.5S; evs.inactive_timeout = PT15S; evs.join_retrans_period = PT1S; evs.max_install_timeouts = 3; evs.send_window = 4; evs.stats_report_period = PT1M; evs.suspect_timeout = PT5S; evs.user_send_window = 2; evs.view_forget_timeout = PT24H; gcache.dir = /var/lib/mysql/; gcache.keep_pages_size = 0; gcache.mem_size = 0; gcache.name = /var/lib/mysql//galera.cache; gcache.page_size = 128M; gcache.size = 128M; gcs.fc_debug = 0; gcs.fc_factor = 1.0; gcs.fc_limit = 16; gcs.fc_master_slave = no; gcs.max_packet_size = 64500; gcs.max_throttle = 0.25; gcs.recv_q_hard_limit = 9223372036854775807; gcs.recv_q_soft_limit = 0.25; gcs.sync_donor = no; gmcast.segment = 0; gmcast.version = 0; pc.announce_timeout = PT3S; pc.checksum = false; pc.ignore_quorum = false; pc.ignore_sb = false; pc.npv
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: o = false; pc.recovery 
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: -1, protocol version: -1
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_sst_grab()
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: Start replication
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: Setting initial position to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: protonet asio version 0
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: Using CRC-32C for message checksums.
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: backend: asio
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: restore pc from disk successfully
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: GMCast version 0
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: (66b559a2, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') listening at tcp://0.0.0.0:4567
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: (66b559a2, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') multicast: , ttl: 1
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: EVS version 0
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connecting to group 'bfm_cluster', peer '10.1.1.141:,10.1.1.142:'
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Warning] WSREP: (66b559a2, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') address 'tcp://10.1.1.142:4567' points to own listening address, blacklisting
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: (66b559a2, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') address 'tcp://10.1.1.142:4567' pointing to uuid 66b559a2 is blacklisted, skipping
May  7 19:45:33 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:33 [Note] WSREP: (66b559a2, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting on, nonlive peers: 
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: declaring dc2b490d at tcp://10.1.1.141:4567 stable
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: re-bootstrapping prim from partitioned components
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(PRIM,66b559a2,12) memb {
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #01166b559a2,0
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011dc2b490d,0
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: } joined {
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: } left {
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: } partitioned {
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: })
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: save pc into disk
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: clear restored view
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connected
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: Changing maximum packet size to 64500, resulting msg size: 32636
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: Shifting CLOSED -> OPEN (TO: 0)
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: Opened channel 'bfm_cluster'
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete.
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = yes, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 0, memb_num = 2
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: STATE_EXCHANGE: sent state UUID: 279db665-f513-11e4-9149-aa318d13ebc4
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: sent state msg: 279db665-f513-11e4-9149-aa318d13ebc4
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 279db665-f513-11e4-9149-aa318d13ebc4 from 0 (sql1)
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 279db665-f513-11e4-9149-aa318d13ebc4 from 1 (sql3)
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Warning] WSREP: Quorum: No node with complete state:
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Version      : 3
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Flags        : 0x1
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Protocols    : 0 / 7 / 3
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011State        : NON-PRIMARY
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Prim state   : NON-PRIMARY
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Prim UUID    : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Prim  seqno  : -1
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011First seqno  : -1
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Last  seqno  : -1
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Prim JOINED  : 0
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011State UUID   : 279db665-f513-11e4-9149-aa318d13ebc4
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Group UUID   : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Name         : 'sql1'
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Incoming addr: '10.1.1.142:3306'
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Version      : 3
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Flags        : 0x2
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Protocols    : 0 / 7 / 3
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011State        : NON-PRIMARY
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Prim state   : SYNCED
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Prim UUID    : b65a0277-f50f-11e4-a916-dbeff5b65a2e
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Prim  seqno  : 8
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011First seqno  : -1
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Last  seqno  : 0
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Prim JOINED  : 1
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011State UUID   : 279db665-f513-11e4-9149-aa318d13ebc4
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Group UUID   : dc2be55b-f506-11e4-8748-4bd7f3fc795c
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Name         : 'sql3'
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Incoming addr: '10.1.1.141:3306'
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: Full re-merge of primary b65a0277-f50f-11e4-a916-dbeff5b65a2e found: 1 of 1.
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011version    = 3,
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011component  = PRIMARY,
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011conf_id    = 8,
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011members    = 1/2 (joined/total),
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011act_id     = 0,
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011last_appl. = -1,
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011protocols  = 0/7/3 (gcs/repl/appl),
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011group UUID = dc2be55b-f506-11e4-8748-4bd7f3fc795c
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [23, 23]
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: Shifting OPEN -> PRIMARY (TO: 0)
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: State transfer required: 
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Group state: dc2be55b-f506-11e4-8748-4bd7f3fc795c:0
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: #011Local state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: dc2be55b-f506-11e4-8748-4bd7f3fc795c:0, view# 9: Primary, number of nodes: 2, my index: 0, protocol version 3
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Warning] WSREP: Gap in state sequence. Need state transfer.
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:34 [Note] WSREP: Running: 'wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'joiner' --address '10.1.1.142' --auth 'cluster:password' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --defaults-file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' --parent '12278' --binlog '/var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin' '
May  7 19:45:34 ns514282 rsyncd[12428]: rsyncd version 3.0.9 starting, listening on port 4444
May  7 19:45:37 ns514282 mysqld: 150507 19:45:37 [Note] WSREP: (66b559a2, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting off
May  7 19:45:47 ns514282 /usr/sbin/irqbalance: Load average increasing, re-enabling all cpus for irq balancing
May  7 19:45:57 ns514282 /usr/sbin/irqbalance: Load average increasing, re-enabling all cpus for irq balancing
May  7 19:46:02 ns514282 /USR/SBIN/CRON[16491]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 50 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
May  7 19:46:03 ns514282 /etc/init.d/mysql[16711]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
May  7 19:46:03 ns514282 /etc/init.d/mysql[16711]: #007/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
May  7 19:46:03 ns514282 /etc/init.d/mysql[16711]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111 "Connection refused")'
May  7 19:46:03 ns514282 /etc/init.d/mysql[16711]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

This question has countless threads all over the internet. Some with no answers. Some of the ones that do have answers

[ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310146/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run) - my disk space is not full

[Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566536/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysqld-sock) - no answer. But as per comments, the mysql.sock does exist and has mysql.mysql ownership.

[ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run) - server is installed, again socket is present in the right location

I have also read that this might be a permissions issue on /var/run/mysqld, but I have checked this and gave it mysql.mysql ownership.

If nothing else, this is an attempt to revive this issue. Any direction is really appreciated.

Thank you,

**Update:**  my.cnf for both nodes. It is the default my.cnf. The only change is commenting out the `bind-address=127.0.0.1` line.

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc_messages_dir = /usr/share/mysql
lc_messages = en_US
skip-external-locking

# bind-address      = 127.0.0.1

max_connections     = 100
connect_timeout     = 5
wait_timeout        = 600
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_cache_size       = 128
sort_buffer_size    = 4M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
tmp_table_size      = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M

myisam_recover          = BACKUP
key_buffer_size     = 128M
table_open_cache    = 400
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 512M
concurrent_insert   = 2
read_buffer_size    = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 1M

query_cache_limit       = 128K
query_cache_size        = 64M

log_warnings        = 2

slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
long_query_time = 10
log_slow_verbosity  = query_plan

log_bin         = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
log_bin_index       = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

default_storage_engine  = InnoDB

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 8M
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_open_files   = 400
innodb_io_capacity  = 400
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

**Update**
Also, I tested, and If I attempt to start the node regularly on its own, (without the cluster, with no extra settings, just defaults) it works.

Comment: Can you also paste the contents of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`? The log doesn't show that mysqld started listening on the unix socket but mysqladmin is attempting to ping thru this socket.

Comment: @alvits Thank you for the reply. I have updated the question. Is there maybe an option I can do for more verbose logging?

Comment: The defauly my.cnf isn't telling mysqld to listen on either localhost nor mysqld.sock. What you can do is - in`debian.cnf`, within the `[client]` section, change `host=localhost` to `host=10.1.1.139` and `host=10.1.1.140` for each nodes correspondingly. Finally, remove the line `socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`. Let me know how it went.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, our team has moved on with Percona (which installed without any issues). I don't want to abandon this though, so I will set up this environment and test your suggestions later today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend restarting the server.

if you keep having problems ...
backup, uninstall and install again ...

with me it worked like this ...

Verify that all IPS used are BIND compliant

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25016681)

Comment: Verify that all IPS used are BIND compliant

Answer (score 0):

Is the "***wsrep_node_name***" correct?

```
[mysqld]
#mysql settings
bind-address=10.1.1.140
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
binlog_format=ROW 
default_storage_engine=innodb 
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2 
innodb_doublewrite=1

#galery settings
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://10.1.1.139,10.1.1.140"
wsrep_sst_method=rsync 
wsrep_cluster_name="sql_cluster" 
wsrep_node_incoming_address=10.1.1.140 
wsrep_sst_receive_address=10.1.1.140 
wsrep_sst_auth=cluster:password 
wsrep_node_address='10.1.1.140' 
wsrep_node_name='sql1' <== ???
wsrep_on=ON
```